# unable to fire valid request using angular and spring

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, spring-mvc

while working on web-services in spring REST with angular I am not able to perform any action on it as following is my code 
@cartRestcontroller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/cart")
public class CartRestController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void addItem(String productId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String sessionId = request.getSession(true).getId();

        Cart cart = cartService.read(sessionId);

        if (cart == null)
            cart = cartService.create(cart);

        Product product = productService.getProductById(productId);
        System.out.println(product.getName());
        if (product == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product does not exist");

        cart.addCartItem(new CartItem(product));

        cartService.update(sessionId, cart);
    }

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason = "Please verify your payload")
    public void handleServerErrors(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
```

my controller for this job

```
var cartApp =   angular.module('cartApp',   []);
cartApp.controller('cartCtrl',  function ($scope, $http)    {
        console.log("Inside Controller");
        $scope.refreshCart  =   function(cartId)    {
                $http.get('/webstore_ecommerce/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId)
                .success(function(data) {
                        $scope.cart =   data;
                });
        };
        $scope.clearCart    =   function()  {
            $http.delete('/webstore_ecommerce/rest/cart/'+$scope.cartId)
            .success($scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId));

    };

    $scope.initCartId   =   function(cartId){
            $scope.cartId=cartId;
            $scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId);
    };

    $scope.addToCart = function(productId)  {

            $http.put('/webstore_ecommerce/rest/cart/add/'+productId)
            .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.refreshCart($http.get('webstore_ecommerce/rest/cart/get/cartId'));
                    conslole.log("Sucess, added to cart");
                    alert("Product  Successfully    added   to  the Cart!");
            });
    };
    $scope.removeFromCart   =   function(productId) {
            $http.put('/webstore_ecommerce/rest/cart/remove/'+productId)
            .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.refreshCart($http.get('/webstore_ecommerce/rest/cart/get/cartId'));
            });
    };
});
```

and my addTocart button

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webstore_ecommerce/resource/js/controllers.js"></script>
<title>Products</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Products</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="container" ng-app="cartApp">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img
                    src="<c:url value="/resource/images/${product.productId}.png"></c:url>"
                    alt="image" style="width: 100%" />

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <h3>${product.name}</h3>
                <p>${product.description}</p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Item Code : </strong><span class="label label-warning">${product.productId}</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>manufacturer</strong> : ${product.manufacturer}
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>category</strong> : ${product.category}
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Condition</strong> : ${product.condition}
                </p>
                <p>
                    <strong>Availble units in stock </strong> : ${product.unitsInStock}
                </p>
                <h4>${product.unitPrice}USD</h4>
                <p ng-controller="cartCtrl">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-large"
                        ng-click="addToCart('${product.productId}')"> <span
                        class="glyphicon-shopping-cart glyphicon"></span> Order Now
                    </a> <a href="<spring:url value="/cart" />" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon-hand-right glyphicon"></span> View Cart
                    </a> <a href="<spring:url value="/products" />" class="btn btn-default">
                        <span class="glyphicon-hand-left glyphicon"></span> back
                    </a>

                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

and this is the error I am getting right now

E

> rror: conslole is not defined
>   $scope.addToCart@http://localhost:8080/webstore_ecommerce/resource/js/controllers.js:25:3
>   Lc/u/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:70:32
>   cc[c]https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:138:373
>   Rc/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:85:412
>   Rc/this.$gethttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:86:1
>   cc[c]https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:138:353
>   oc/c/<@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:23:13
>   m@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:6:191
>   oc/c@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js:22:490
>   c/<()angular.min.js (line 60) Cc/this.$get
>
> ...n:c("warn"),info:c("info"),error:c("error")}}]}function
>   Jc(b,a){function c(a){re...

**Edit**
If I fire request using postman, everything is working fine
**Edit** This is error That I am getting from stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.local.domain.repo.impl.CartRepositiryImpl.create(CartRepositiryImpl.java:22)
    at com.local.domain.service.impl.CartServiceImpl.create(CartServiceImpl.java:18)
    at com.local.domain.comtrollers.CartRestController.addItem(CartRestController.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:745)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

my  cartRepositiry

@Repository
public class CartRepositiryImpl implements CartRepositiry {

```
Map<String, Cart> listOfCarts;

    public CartRepositiryImpl() {
        listOfCarts = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Cart create(Cart cart) {
        if (listOfCarts.containsKey(cart.getCartId()))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cart with id : (%s) already exists", cart.getCartId()));

        listOfCarts.put(cart.getCartId(), cart);
        return cart;
    }
```

and this is what firebug returns :

"NetworkError: 500  - http://localhost:8080/webstore_ecommerce/rest/cart/add/P1235" P1235
Since I am new to this Please help me to solve this, any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wrote conslole instead of console... You better go to bed or have a coffee break :)

```
===> conslole.log("Sucess, added to cart");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but now I am getting some real errors

Comment: Can you update your answer with the new error? Because you are saying it is working correctly with Postman, and from what I see, the AngularJS app was crashing because of the "cons-lol-e" :p

Comment: Ok, where do you call `public CartRepositiryImpl()` ? It need to be called before `create`, because listOfCarts is not initialized

Comment: after debugging I came to know that my method `addToCart(productId)` is null